# laravel dynamic route groups using year

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a site that pulls a lot of data and it is all tied to a specific year. I was trying to think of the best way to add a dynamic route group that included the year so that it would always be showing for the user and that I could use in my models.

Something like www.site.com/2015/dashboard

I can do this using a standard route group, but it requires me to add the route perameters to every method I use.

Is there a better way to use something like this and have the year available to the controller at all times and not have to send it with each route?

Answer (score 1):

Type this in routes.php

```
$year= Request::segment(1);
Route::group(['prefix'=>$year], function() {
    Route::get('dashboard', ['uses' => 'SomeController@someMethod']);
});
```

And in your controller pick year:

```
$year = Request::segment(1)
```